# java com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, syntax-error

I am working on a program for a class assignment and I keep getting a sql syntax error. I have the jar and it seems that my program is connected to the database and that JBDC driver is loaded as well but i'm getting this com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException error message. I can't for the life of me find out what is wrong with the code.

```
package application;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Info extends Application {

    private String query = " ";
    private TextArea text = new TextArea();
    private TextField where = new TextField();
    private PreparedStatement statement;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        HBox hboxTop = new HBox(10);
        CheckBox check_ID = new CheckBox("customer ID");
        CheckBox check_Name = new CheckBox("name");
        CheckBox check_Address = new CheckBox("address");
        CheckBox check_City = new CheckBox("city");
        CheckBox check_State = new CheckBox("state");
        CheckBox check_Zip = new CheckBox("zip");
        hboxTop.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
        hboxTop.getChildren().addAll(check_ID, check_Name, check_Address, check_City, check_State, check_Zip);

        VBox vbox1 = new VBox(10);
        Button btSubmit = new Button("Submit");
        vbox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox1.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        vbox1.getChildren().add(btSubmit);
        HBox hbox2 = new HBox(10);
        Label label = new Label("Type the where condition: ");
        where.setPrefColumnCount(40);
        hbox2.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        hbox2.getChildren().addAll(label, where);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        pane.setTop(hboxTop);
        pane.setLeft(hbox2);
        pane.setBottom(text);
        pane.setRight(vbox1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("PC PARTS");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = e -> {
            if (check_ID.isSelected())
                query = query + "custid,";
            if (check_Name.isSelected())
                query = query + "name,";
            if (check_Address.isSelected())
                query = query + "address,";
            if (check_City.isSelected())
                query = query + "city,";
            if (check_State.isSelected())
                query = query + "state";
            if (check_Zip.isSelected())
                query = query + "zip,";
        };
        check_ID.setOnAction(handler);
        check_Name.setOnAction(handler);
        check_Address.setOnAction(handler);
        check_City.setOnAction(handler);
        check_State.setOnAction(handler);
        check_Zip.setOnAction(handler);
        btSubmit.setOnAction(e -> {
            initializeDB();
            display();
        });

    }
    private void initializeDB(){
        try{
        //load the JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
        //establish a connection
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pcparts", "root", "sesame");
        System.out.println("Database connected");
        String query_Str = "select" + query + "where" + where.getText();
        // create a statement
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query_Str);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
    private void display(){
            try {
            ResultSet rset = statement.executeQuery();
            if (rset.next()){
            String custid = rset.getString("custid");
            String name = rset.getString("name");
            String address = rset.getString("address");
            String city = rset.getString("city");
            String state = rset.getString("state");
            String zip = rset.getString("zip");
            String finalString =
            filter(custid) + filter(name) + filter(address) + filter(city) + filter(state) + filter(zip);
            text.setText(finalString);
            }
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                public static String filter(String str){
                String x = "";
                if(str != null){
                return str;
                }
                else
                return x;
                }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the information from sql that I am trying to retrieve.

```
mysql> use pcparts;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_pcparts |
+-------------------+
| customers         |
| orders            |
| parts             |
+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM customers;
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| custid  | int(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | char(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address | char(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city    | char(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state   | char(2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| zip     | char(5)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM customers;
+--------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+-------+
| custid | name        | address      | city       | state | zip   |
+--------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+-------+
|      1 | Smith, Tim  | 12 Elm St    | Tampa      | FL    | 34567 |
|      2 | Jones, Tom  | 435 Oak Dr   | Dunedin    | FL    | 33245 |
|      3 | Avery, Bill | 623 Ash Ave  | Clearwater | FL    | 33655 |
|      4 | Kerr, Debra | 1573 Yew Crt | Clearwater | FL    | 33442 |
|      5 | Tater, Dick | 15 Elm St    | Dunedin    | FL    | 33333 |
+--------+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is the error message that comes up in eclipse

```
Driver Loaded
Database connected
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:941)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2550)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at application.Info.display(Info.java:109)
    at application.Info.lambda$1(Info.java:87)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you print `query_Str` please

Comment: query_Str prints          select name,name,address,where

Comment: can you share where.getText() method please

Comment: `select name,name,address,where` is not valid SQL.